# Mongo 5 docker image does not work with current files

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, minikube

I'm running Mongo5 with the docker image mongo:5.0 and minikube with docker-compose.

I'm using my local docker as driver for the minikube since after I upgraded to MacOs Ventura,
`minikube start --vm-driver virtualbox` has stopped working. So I'm starting it with `minikube start --vm-driver docker`

When I startup my Mongo I get the following error:
`This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier`

I've searched about this error and everybody talks about this happening because of the upgrade process of a running database, but this is happening to me even if I start a new database from scratch.

On my docker-compose, the volumes I'm using for the database are:

```
- mongodb:/data/db
- <path>/src/setup/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the use of `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` I was trying to initialize the replicaSet within that folder and that's not possible, we need to first run up the Mongo and when it's up and running add the replicaSet. The entrypoint doesn't guarantee that this will be case